# How to hit 1000 endpoints using multi threading in groovy?

Tags: multithreading, grails, groovy, threadpool, executorservice

I have a requirement to hit **endpoints more than 1000 times** to fetch some data from website. So i read some tutorials to use **Multi Threading** to achieving it. But at a time i want to use only 13 threads **on same method**.

So basically i am using **ExecutorService** to run 13 threads at one time:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(13);
for (int itLocation = 0; itLocation < locationList.size(); itLocation++) {
  //some code like
  ScraperService obj = new ScraperService(threadName,url)
  threadPool.submit(obj);
}
threadPool.shutdown();
```

My Groovy Class named as **ScraperService** is **implementing the Runnable interface**.

```
@Override
        void run() {
            println("In run method...................")
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                someMethod()
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**Problem:**

My problem is that my `ExecutorService.submit(obj)` and `ExecutorService.execute(obj)` is not calling my run() method of Runnable interface.

**In Groovy/Grails:**

There is also a executor plugin [Executor Plugin in grails](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/uberall/grails-executor) but i didn't found any appropriate example how to use it.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `threadPool.invokeAll(tasks);` ? But in your case, I think you have to call `threadPool.awaitTermination()`

Comment: I don't now about threadPool.invokeAll(tasks);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i think there is problem in **groovy service** class with `@Transnational` annotation which doesn't allow to call run() method of Runnable interface. If you'll remove the `@Transnational` then it will call the run() method. It happened also in my case. But i am not sure, there may be some another reason. You can directly use:

```
ExecutorService threadPool =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(13)
threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            void run() {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                                someMethod()
                            }
                        })
```

**Extra (As i read your question)**

If you are using multiple threads on same method then it can be complex as all threads will use the same local variables of that method which can occurs problems. It is better to use  multiple threads for different different work.

But if you want to use same method for executing multiple threads then in my scenario it is better to use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

**newSingleThreadExecutor()** calls a single thread so if you want to execute multiple tasks on it then it does not create multiple threads. Instead, it waits for one task to complete before starting the next task on the same thread.

**Speed:** newSingleThreadExecutor in comparison of multi threads will be slow but safer to use.

Answer (score 4):

GPars is excellent for this type of thing.

Your ScraperService can just be responsible for handling the scraped data like below or maybe fetching it too, whatever.

```
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

def theEndpoint = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk'

def scraperService

GParsPool.withPool( 13 ) {
    (1..1000).eachParallel {
        scraperService.scrape theEndpoint.toURL().text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `threadPool.submit` does not execute task

use `threadPool.execute(obj)` or `threadPool.submit(obj).get()`

instead of `threadPool.submit(obj)`

check the documentation for details:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)

example:

```groovy
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors


ExecutorService pool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)

for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    int x=i;
    Thread.sleep(444);
    pool.execute{
        println "start $x"
        Thread.sleep(3000+x*100);
        println "end   $x"
    }
}

println "done cycle"
pool.shutdown()                 //all tasks submitted
while (!pool.isTerminated()){}  //waitfor termination
println 'Finished all threads'
```

Comment: So if i want to execute 1000 thread then for each thread should i use hreadPool.submit(obj).get(). Actually also using the threadPool.execute(obj) method my call is not going to overrided run() method.

Comment: If you use execute(), you'll not have a way to tell if your runnable was run. Using submit(), you should save all the returned Futures and then loop on them checking get(). Watch out for InterruptedExceptions. Guava's Futures.getUnchecked() can be a big help here.